# Significance of slogan written on the backside of Adrian Harris's car?

Tags: analysis, teen-wolf-tv

In [Teen Wolf (TV Series)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teen_Wolf_%282011_TV_series%29), in one episode probably in Season 1 , there is
slogan written on the back of Adrian Harris's car, states like

> "Imagination is more important then knowledge"

How is this slogan implies here. I mean what is its significance in the show?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an [Albert Einstein quote](http://quotationsbook.com/quote/20417/). The quote signifies the importance of thinking of all possibilities in the world rather than the limited known knowledge. As to the significance, it could just be a cool quote to put on the car to show he's a deep thinker